# Проблемы с контентом по https

Tags: ssl, https

После установки на сайт ssl сертификата, браузер блокирует файлы стилей. Вот в таком формате:

> [blocked] The page at 'https://example.com was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://example.com/images/ru/main.css': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS. Как исправить и заставить этот контент грузиться через https?

Answer (score 2):

Так всё же написано в сообщении браузера :)

У вас на сайте стоят ссылки на элементы, которые грузятся по HTTP, а не по HTTPS. Переделайте их или на относительные, или на ссылки с явным указанием `https://`.

Comment: уже все что можно поменял на https:// но проблема осталась все тоже самое.

Comment: Ссылка? Наверняка что-то пропущено.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите действительно таблицы стилей и скрипты. Возможно где-то там и запряталась абсолютная ссылка с http://
Когда свой сайт переводил на https - перерыл даже php-скрипты.